# Bash script : Cat multiple lines in file containing “$” characters

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, cat, here-document

I'm doing a script to auto-install some stuff including a nginx web server.

I'm creating the nginx conf file like this :

```
cat >/etc/nginx/sites-available/bookstack.conf <<EOL
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificats/domain.tld.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificats/domain.tld.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;

  server_name domain.tld;

  root /path/to/bookstack/public;

  index index.php index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
  }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain.tld;

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

EOL
```

My problem is that cat takes the $ characters as variable names (which normally makes sense) and doesn't put what I want in my *.conf* file. This is a sample of my *.conf* file after the script has done his work :

```
location / {
    try_files  / /index.php?;
  }

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME ;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
```

How to prevent this behaviour please ? I tried using quotes but it didn't work.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you asking how to copy the text exactly as you wrote it?

Comment: Yes i want to copy exactly the text, including the words that have a $.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want any substitution inside the here document (the input to the `<<EOL` construct), use a quote on the delimiter specification. Any quoting will do: you can write `<<'EOL'` (recommended), `<<\EOL`, `<<E''OL`, etc., even (confusingly) `<<"EOL"`.

```
$ cat <<'EOL'
> $foo
> EOL
$foo
```

If you want to expand variable and command substitutions sometimes, keep `<<EOL` and put a backslash before each special characters that you don't want to expand. The special characters that need to be escaped are `` $\` ``.

See the bash manual about [here documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents). This is applicable to plain sh as well.

Comment: <<'EOL' did the trick ! Thanks a lot ! :)